# Почему 1 байт необязательно 8 бит?

Tags: системы-счисления

Если 1 байт необязательно 8 бит, то тогда сколько? Какие бывают значении битов для байта? От чего зависит?

P.S. Знаю что октет это ровно 8 бит.

Comment: Зависит от железки, в теории может быть любым.

Comment: В википедии пишут: [В большинстве вычислительных архитектур байт — это минимальный независимо адресуемый набор данных.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82). Там есть примеры машин с 6, 7, 9, 32 и 36 битными байтами. Могу дополнить -- некоторые модели TMS DSP оперируют 16-битными  байтами.

Answer (score 3):

Например, [поэтому](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)).

"Байт" - это, грубо говоря, абстракция, инкапсулирующая понятие 8 атомарных ячеек памяти. А вот эту "атомарность" уже может определять конкретная архитектура. Железка, если угодно.

Поэтому в низкоуровневых языках(в си, например) даже нет такого типа данных - он определен на уровне псевдонимов - т.е новый уровень абстракции.

P.S Сетунь - как пример "битовой" абстракции. В настоящее время более популярна абстракция "восьми ячеек".

P.P.S [Что такое байт?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.A7.D1.82.D0.BE_.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B5_.C2.AB.D0.B1.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.82.C2.BB.3F)

Comment: Не думаю, что в этом вопросе стоит акцентировать внимание на "абстракции". Я тут немного повспоминал, и думаю, что на самом деле понятие *байт* скорее связано с периферийными устройствами (каналами связи) и обозначает минимальную осмысленную порцию передаваемой информации (в эту порцию могут входить и служебные (синхронизация, четность) биты, отсюда имеем 6, 7 и 9 битные байты), нежели с адресацией памяти.